# Как декодировать строку в юникод в Python?

Tags: python

Есть переменная code='005b' есть ли более простой способ декодировать в символ '['. Сейчас работает так:

```
symbol = bytes('\\u'+code,'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
```

Мне интерсно какой бкдет код если входные данныуе будут '005b005b005b', а выходной результат '[[['.

```
''.join([chr(int(code[i:i+4],16)) for i in range(0,len(code),4)])
```

А можно ли проще?

Comment: `symbol = chr(int(code, 16))`

Comment: @Стас А если в code не 1, а несколько символов? например: code = '005b005b005b'

Comment: @Ivan тогда и ваш код не работает. Приведите примеры входных данных или наборов входных данных и ожидаемый результат.

Comment: @Dmitry мой код работает для одного символа. Мне интерсно какой бкдет код если входные данныуе будут '005b005b005b', а выходной результат '[[['

Comment: @Ivan это более чем понятно, просто добавьте эти данные в сам вопрос нажав ссылку [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1331874/edit) под вашим вопросом.